# Is there any way to generate a set of JWebUnit tests from an apache rewrite config?

Tags: apache, unit-testing, mod-rewrite

Seems unlikely, but is there any way to generate a set of unit tests for the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule   ^/(user|group|country)/([a-z]+)/(photos|videos)$       http:/whatever?type=$1&entity=$2&resource=$3
```

From this I'd like to generate a set of urls of the form:

- /user/foo/photos
- /user/bar/photos
- /group/baz/videos
- /country/bar/photos
- etc...

The reason I don't want to just do this once by hand is that I'd like the bounded alternation groups (e.g. `(user|group|country)`) to be able to grow and maintain coverage without having the update the tests by hand.

Is there a rewrite rule or regex parser that might be able to do this, or am I doing it by hand?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind hacking a few lines of Perl then there's a package, [Regexp::Genex](http://search.cpan.org/~bowmanbs/Regexp-Genex-0.07/lib/Regexp/Genex.pm) that you can use to generate something close to what you require e.g.

```
# perl -MRegexp::Genex=:all -le 'print for strings(qr/\/(user|group|country)\/([a-z]+)\//)'
/user/dxb/
/user/dx/
/user/d/
/group/xd/
/group/x/
#  perl -MRegexp::Genex=:all -le 'my $re=qr/\/(user|group|country)\/([a-z]+)\/(phone|videos)/;$Regexp::Genex::DEFAULT_LEN = length $re;print for strings($re)'
/user/mgcgmccdmgdmmzccgmczgmzzdcmmd/phone
/user/mgcgmccdmgdmmzccgmczgmzzdcmm/phone
/user/mgcgmccdmgdmmzccgmczgmzzdcm/phone
/user/mgcgmccdmgdmmzccgmczgmzzdc/phone

...

/group/gg/videos
/group/g/phone
/group/g/videos
/country/jvmmm/phone
/country/jvmmm/videos
/country/jvmm/phone
/country/jvmm/videos
/country/jvm/phone
/country/jvm/videos
/country/jv/phone
/country/jv/videos
/country/j/phone
/country/j/videos
#
```

Note:

1) You'll need to write a wrapper to parse the source file, tokenise (extract) the source patterns, escape certain characters in the rule e.g. "/", and possibly split your rules into more manageable parts, before expanding, via Genex, and then outputting the results, in the desired format.

2) To install the module type: **cpan  Regexp::Genex**